# Display Parent-Child Posts in specific order by comparing IDs in array

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, wp-query, order

I have an array of IDs stored for custom post type "service".
Some of these are parent IDs and some of these are child IDs.

So "**service**" post type here is hierarchical.

Now from this array of IDs, I want to list pages in the format so that:

1. They are sorted by post title, ascending order.
2. They are listed in parent > child pattern like this:

   ```
   Service 1
       A Child
       B Child
   Service 2
       X Child
       Y Child
   Service 3
   ```
3. Also as the array contains any IDs, if there is child ID in the array, but parent ID is not then **show the parent post automatically**.

So far below is the code I have implemented:

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'service' ),
    'posts_per_page' => '-1',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post__in' => $service_ids_array,
);

$all_services = new WP_Query( $args );
```

But, this just gets all the services from the array of IDs sorted by title.

Here is a logic I am trying to implement, but if there is a better solution, I am happy to use that.

So my logic was, to get all the posts from array that are on root level. So parent ID = 0.
After that I run a loop of these IDs and in the loop I check if their child IDs exist in the `$service_ids_array` or not. And show if they exist.

But what if there are only child IDs in the array? In that case this logic will not succeed.

Comment: How did you end up with this array? I have to wonder if you are trying to solve the wrong problem. Perhaps you need a better array?

Comment: The array is coming from a custom field data

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll just need to loop the loop and first build a helper array to contain the hierarchy, then work with that to print out any necessary html. Caching the resulting helper array to a transient might be a good idea to save processing time.

```
// is there a transient?
$transient = get_transient( "parent_children_ids_{$post_id}" );

if ( ! $transient ) {
  // initial query
  $all_services = new WP_Query( $args );
  
  // first sort found posts to a helper associative array
  $posts_by_id = array();
  foreach ($all_services->posts as $service) {
    $posts_by_id[$service->ID]$service;
  }
  
  // create hierarchy array
  $parent_children_ids = array();
  // track parents IDs that are not in found posts
  $missing_parent_ids = array();
  
  // WP_Query by default returns array of WP_Post objects
  // WP_Post has a property post_parent, which is the ID of the parent post, if such is set
  foreach ($all_services->posts as $service) {
    // add parents as top level keys
    if ( ! $service->post_parent ) {
      if ( ! isset($parent_children_ids[$service->ID]) ) {
        $parent_children_ids[$service->ID] = array();
      }
      continue;
    }
  
    // add the parent to the array, if it hasn't been added already
    if ( ! isset( $parent_children_ids[$service->post_parent] ) ) {
      $parent_children_ids[$service->post_parent] = array();
    }
  
    // should the parent be queried
    if ( ! isset( $posts_by_id[$service->post_parent] ) ) {
      $missing_parent_ids[] = $service->post_parent;
    }
  
    // append the post to the child array
    $parent_children_ids[$service->post_parent][] = $service->ID;
  }
  
  // query the missing parent posts
  if ( $missing_parent_ids ) {
    $missing_parents = new WP_Query('post__in' => $missing_parent_ids);
    // push the found posts to the posts helper array
    foreach ($missing_parents->posts as $service) {
      $posts_by_id[$service->ID]$service;
    }
  }

  // do some further sorting, if needed..
  
  // perhaps save the $parent_children_ids to an transient
  // to skip the previous processing for a suitable length of time
  // remember to clear the transient when the source data changes to have the transient rebuilt
  set_transient( "parent_children_ids_{$post_id}", $parent_children_ids, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
} else {
  $parent_children_ids = $transient;
}

// loop the parents and chilrend array
foreach ($parent_children_ids as $parent_id => $child_ids) {
  $parent = $posts_by_id[$parent_id];
  // parent code..

  foreach ($child_ids as $child_id) {
    $child = $posts_by_id[$child_id];
    // child code...
  }
}
```